# Problems using QT.cls

Tags: document-classes

I am attempting to use the class file qt.cls, available [at the journal's website,](https://www.ems-ph.org/journals/authorinfo.php?jrn=qt) but when I try to compile, even just using their example document in TexShop v3.61, I get the error:

[image]

and when I go to the spot in the class file where this occurs, it looks like this:

```
\@ifpackageloaded{amstex}{%
  \def\@tempa{TT}%
}{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{amsmath}{%
    \def\@tempb#1 v#2.#3\@nil{#2}%
    \ifnum\@xp\@xp\@xp\@tempb\csname ver@amsmath.sty\endcsname v0.0\@nil
       <\tw@
      \def\@tempa{TT}%
    \else
      \def\@tempa{TF}%
    \fi
  }{%
    \def\@tempa{TF}
  }%
}
\if\@tempa
  \renewcommand{\math@qedhere}{\quad\hbox{\qedsymbol}}%
\fi
\newcommand{\openbox}{\leavevmode
  \hbox to.77778em{%
  \hfil\vrule
  \vbox to.675em{\hrule width.6em\vfil\hrule}%
  \vrule\hfil}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textsquare}{%
  \begingroup \usefont{U}{msa}{m}{n}\thr@@\endgroup
}
\providecommand{\qedsymbol}{\openbox}
\newenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\providecommand{\proofname}{Proof}
```

Can anyone figure out what the problem is here? I am a newcomer to the forum, so please feel free to re-tag.

Comment: @barbarabeeton seems they are messing with `\[`, wasn't `\[` made robust by default in a recent `amsmath` update? Line 1284, right before looking for `amstex`

Comment: well, i was mistaken -- the trap for `amstex` *is* still in the public version of `amsthm`, which is embedded in full in this document class, with only minor modifications of a reasonable nature.  however, what is shown in your error message isn't an accurate copy of what's in `QT.cls` that i just downloaded.  there should be a closing brace just before `\@ifpackageloaded{amstex}` and it's missing.  that would explain the `Paragraph ended` error.  but there's lots more missing there.  i think you have a corrupted `QT.cls` file.

Comment: @barbarabeeton where exactly is that brace missing? I seem to have a `}` right above `\@ifpackageloaded{amstex}{%`, ahh, no `amsmath` is even used. Was it the core that made `\[`  robust?

Comment: @daleif -- brace missing from line 1286 of the version of `QT.cls` that i just downloaded, right after the `\@nil`.  there's another problem i spotted: `amsthm` checks to see if `amsmath` is loaded, but `QT.cls` doesn't load `amsmath` (with `\RequirePackage{amsmath}`) until after the embedded `amsthm`.  but that wouldn't cause the error as reported.  and i don't see `\x@protect` *anywhere* in `QT.cls`, so i don't know how it got into the error report in the log.

Comment: @daleif: so is the robustness of \[  causing an error because there's no closing \] on line 1286?

Comment: @barbarabeeton look right before those line, it is messing with `\[`, outcomment that and it compiles just fine (with some warnings about some very early ifnums)

Comment: looking at the edited code segment, the problem occurs *before* that.  there should be (just) a closing brace on the line before `\@ifpackageloaded{amstex}`. that's missing from the error message. i still suspect a corrupted `QT.cls` file.

Comment: @daleif -- what happens if you move the `\RequirePackage{amsmath}` to precede the included `amsthm`?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: That closing brace is in my QT.cls file. I don't know why it's not in the error message.

Comment: @JimConant no, I'm just guessing that because `\[` is now robust in the core, one cannot make redefinitions like that any more and that is what fails (do not know the details)

Comment: @barbarabeeton don't you see the stuff with `\def\[`??

Comment: @daleif: That sounds right. They probably need to revise their style file. It doesn't look like there's an easy fix.

Comment: @JimConant the QT file is dated 2013, before that core kernel update. And since the file is not on ctan it is pretty hard to test for it

Comment: @daleif -- yes i do see the stuff with `\def\[`.  but if that were a problem, i'm sure we'd have had complaints from ams authors long ago, and this is the first i've heard of it.  the log shows pdftex from tex live 2015, so it doesn't seem that any of the newest (2016) changes are involved.  (and i'm scared silly about that possibility.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton, it is just interesting that if outcomment that line it runs fine

Comment: @daleif -- you mean comment out *just* the one line with `\def\[`, leaving an empty `\def\@tempa{}`?  does it still produce a proper end-of-proof marker on a terminal display math block?  (i'll put this on the list of things that needs to be investigated/researched.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton i commented out the line right after where the tempa is used. Then it compiled, never looked at the output (is afk)

Comment: @daleif  @barbarabeeton I commented out the line  `\expandafter\@tempa\[\@nil` and it seems to compile normally. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this has nothing to do with TeXShop.

Second it has everything to do with the `QT.cls` file. There are several `\RequirePackage` lines around line 1339. Copy all of those lines and duplicate them just after the `\ProcessOptions` line at line 130. You can then remove the original lines if you wish. The example file compiles fine afterward.

That's what happens when a class file isn't updated when necessary.

Hopefully that fixes the problem in all cases.

Comment: Welcome back to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 0):

I followed daleif's idea and commented out the line `\expandafter\@tempa\[\@nil` from the qt.cls class file. It seems to compile normally now.